# Gulp imagemin skip folder creation if folder already exists

Tags: npm, gulp, gulp-imagemin, gulp-dest

Im new to Gulp but managed to create the following gulpfile.js to minify images that reside in an /image/ folder and output to my /images/optimised/ folder:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');

function minifyimages() {

    return gulp.src('./images/*')
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('images/optimised'))
    verbose: true
}

exports.minifyimages = minifyimages;
```

If i run the script for the first time it generates the /images/optimised/ folder on its own, which is fine. But if i run it again then it generates an /images/optimised/optimised/ folder.

Is there a way for it to skip the creation of the /optimised/ folder if it already exists?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this task:

```js
function minifyimages() {

    return gulp.src('./images/*.+(gif|png)')   // change here
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./images/optimised'))
    verbose: true
}
```

I added the file extensions to `gulp.src` (you may have more image types) so that gulp is not looking into the `optimized` folder at all.  And thus optimizing those as well, with their folder structure.